# How to rollback database migrations when switching back to previous application version

Tags: node.js, database, database-migration, rollback, umzug

In my nodejs application, i am using a library(Umzug) which will handle database migrations with the help of migration files where each migration file contains up(to execute the migration) and down(to rollback the migration) functions

Migration files will be added as required to the code which creates a new version for the application and new migrations will run at the start of the application

My question is when switching back to older version of the application, i need to rollback the migrations that are not present in the older version of the application. how can i do it when the older version doesn't contain the files that are in the newer version?